# Webbrowser Control, Flash not working

Tags: vb.net, flash, browser, web

I know this problem has been around forever and hopefully someone can point me to a solution.
I created a simple web browser program (using VS 2013 Ultimate) to automate changing from urls by just clicking a button. It's for children so they don't need to navigate, they just push a button and it takes them to the next url.

Problem: Flash content will not display using the webbrowser control. It will display in iexplorer 11 that is installed on the computer. It will also display in VS 2013 when I run the code to debug (see solution 3 below). Using Windows 7. I think it did load the page the very first time I ran it. After that, it will not load no matter what. (That makes me think it has something to do with a cached copy)

Solutions I have tried: I have changed all the relevant and at times unrelevant featurecontrol settings in the registry. EX: FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION 
I have also tried modifying the url to be unique.
I have also tried deleting the history, files, caches for iexplorer. Ex: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8") This last solution makes the flash load every time perfectly while I run the program within VS 2013. But when I run the program independently outside of the VS environment, it again refuses to load the flash content.

I am willing to accept all solutions or suggested alternatives to the webbrowser control. But the alternative must be a free solution and up to date solution.
If possible, I want to stay with the webbrowser control with a solution given. As a side note: using VB.net to code. 
If I forgot anything or need more information, let me know.

Edit: some of the websites in question link:

```
http://boowakwala.uptoten.com/kids/boowakwala-island-moving-furnituremove.html
http://boowakwala.uptoten.com/kids/boowakwala-adventures-chocolate-eggsort.html
http://boowakwala.uptoten.com/kids/boowakwala-island-moving-furnituremove.html
```

Comment: I think the WebBrowserControl only supports a subset of what IE supports and I don't believe extensions/add-ons are supported.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has come to this thread for a solution, sorry it took so long to write it.

The problem was as I suspected, the webbrowser control uses a cached copy of the web page. Thus it will not load the flash content. Simple and fast way to fix without code: In Internet Option of iexplorer, under the General tab, select Settings. In the Temporary Internet Files tab, select Every Time I Visit The Webpage. This will keep the control from loading a cached copy. The flash content will now load as normal.